# getting contacts from a specified group in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to get contacts from a specific group of known id.i'm able to get group id and contact names in that group.but i'm unable to get contact numbers.tried some solutions from google search, but every time i'm getting phone number same as group id , if i query group for phone numbers and contact names using Phone.number , Phone.DISPLAY_NAME.if i use below method i'm getting error
please help me to figure out whats wrong in my code.

Code :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.group_contacts);
        addGroups = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectGroup);

        groupAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, GroupCursor(),
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        setListAdapter(groupAdapter);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        addGroups.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(myGroups.this, Main.class);
                Bundle carry = new Bundle();
                carry.putStringArrayList("numbers", cNumbers);
                carry.putStringArrayList("name", cNames);
                intent.putExtras(carry);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    private Cursor GroupCursor() {

        String[] projection = { ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,
                ContactsContract.Groups._ID };
        Cursor gCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, projection, null,                   null,
                ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE);

        // int idcolumn = gCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID);
        // String id = gCursor.getString(idcolumn);

        // Log.d(E, "group id : " + id );
        return gCursor;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Log.d(E, "id : " + id);
        String groupId = Long.toString(id);

        String[] cProjection = { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME ,Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts._ID};

        Cursor groupCursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                cProjection,
                CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + "= ?",
                new String[]{groupId}, null);
        if (groupCursor != null) {
            groupCursor.moveToFirst();
            do {

                int nameCoumnIndex = groupCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

                String name = groupCursor.getString(nameCoumnIndex);

                String cId = groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));

                Cursor numberCursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Phone.NUMBER}, Phone._ID +"="+cId, null, null);
                numberCursor.moveToFirst();
                int numberColumnIndex = numberCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                Log.d(E, "numberindex : " + numberColumnIndex);

                String number = numberCursor.getString(numberColumnIndex);

                cNumbers.add(number);

                Log.d(E, "contact " + name + ":" + number);

                cNames.add(name);
            } while (groupCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Log :

```
 09-04 17:59:24.943: D/dalvikvm(18084): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 23K, 48% free 2844K/5379K, external 1032K/1039K, paused 24ms
09-04 17:59:26.054: D/(18084): id : 14
09-04 17:59:26.074: D/(18084): numberindex : 0
09-04 17:59:26.074: D/AndroidRuntime(18084): Shutting down VM
09-04 17:59:26.074: W/dalvikvm(18084): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015568)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at hm.swarna.groupsms.myGroups.onListItemClick(myGroups.java:117)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3535)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1827)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
09-04 17:59:26.084: E/AndroidRuntime(18084):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 17:59:27.556: I/Process(18084): Sending signal. PID: 18084 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You keep the "// TODO Auto-generated method stub" when you allready implemented them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use following code in your onListItemClick method:

```
long groupId = id;
    String[] cProjection = { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID };

    Cursor groupCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI,
            cProjection,
            CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + "= ?" + " AND "
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE + "='"
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(groupId) }, null);
    if (groupCursor != null && groupCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {

            int nameCoumnIndex = groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

            String name = groupCursor.getString(nameCoumnIndex);

            long contactId = groupCursor.getLong(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID));

            Cursor numberCursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { Phone.NUMBER }, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, null);

            if (numberCursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                int numberColumnIndex = numberCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                do
                {
                    String phoneNumber = numberCursor.getString(numberColumnIndex);
                    Log.d("your tag", "contact " + name + ":" + phoneNumber);
                } while (numberCursor.moveToNext());
                numberCursor.close();
            }
        } while (groupCursor.moveToNext());
        groupCursor.close();
    }
```

You need to specify mimetype when querying for contacts, which belong to specified group. And because single contact can have multiple phone numbers, you may need to query all of them.

**EDIT:**
To get all groups with at least one contact with phone number you can use following query:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri groupsUri = ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_SUMMARY_URI;
String where = "((" + ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE + " = 1) AND (" 
                + ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES + "!= 0))";
Cursor cursor = cr.query(groupsUri, null, where, null, null);
```

As for getting contacts with phone number from a specified group - I don't know simple solution.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get contacts with phone number from a group and also groups with at least one contact ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answwer to what you are asking for. Get all phone-numbers from specific group #name. This spagetti can surely be shorter, if you use some time on it, to optimize it a bit.

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllNumbersFromGroupId(String navn)
{
    String selection = ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + "=? and " + ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { "0", "1" };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int len = cursor.getCount();

    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE));
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID));

        if (title.equals(navn))
        {
            String[] cProjection = { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID };

            Cursor groupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    cProjection,
                    CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + "= ?" + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE + "='"
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null);
            if (groupCursor != null && groupCursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {

                    int nameCoumnIndex = groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

                    String name = groupCursor.getString(nameCoumnIndex);

                    long contactId = groupCursor.getLong(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID));

                    Cursor numberCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            new String[] { Phone.NUMBER }, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, null);

                    if (numberCursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        int numberColumnIndex = numberCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                        do
                        {
                            String phoneNumber = numberCursor.getString(numberColumnIndex);
                            numbers.add(phoneNumber);
                        } while (numberCursor.moveToNext());
                        numberCursor.close();
                    }
                } while (groupCursor.moveToNext());
                groupCursor.close();
            }
            break;
        }

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    return numbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getContactsForGroup(String groupID, Activity activity){
    Cursor dataCursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{                                                     // PROJECTION
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
                    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,         // contact name
                    ContactsContract.Data.DATA1                 // group
            },
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? " + "AND " +               // SELECTION
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 +    " = ? ",           // set groupID
            new String[]{                                                     // SELECTION_ARGS
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                    groupID
            },
            null);
    dataCursor.moveToFirst();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (dataCursor.moveToNext()) //
    {
        String s0 = dataCursor.getString(0);                //contact_id
        String s1 = dataCursor.getString(1);                //contact_name
        String s2 = dataCursor.getString(2);                //group_id
        Log.d("tag", "contact_id: " + s0 + "  contact: " + s1 + "   groupID: "+ s2);
        map.put(s0, s1);
    }
    return map;
}
```